# Filename into the header of samefile using batch script

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

I am trying to extract the some part of filename into the header  samefile using batch script.

For example:
there are 30 files loaded with data 
abc_1.txt
abc_2.txt
abc_3.txt
abc_4.txt
abc_5.txt
.
.
.
abc_30.txt

I need the Output should be for abc_1.txt file -header as xyz|1, 
                               abc_2.txt file -header as xyz|2,
                               abc_3.txt file -header as xyz|3,
                               abc_4.txt file -header as xyz|4,
                               abc_5.txt file -header as xyz|5,
                               .
                               .
                               .
                               abc_30.txt file -header as xyz|30

Please suggest how to load these specfic header into the same file using batch script..!!

Thanks in Advance.
Joe

Comment: Have you tried something? Show us what you tried, then we can help you to spot the problems.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
for %%G in (*.txt) echo %%G >> mynewfile.txt
```

The for command gets all the files matching the mask in the parentheses.

The ECHO sends the matched file name to mynewfile.txt

The >> tells the echo command to append (not overwrite)

I recommend that mynewfile.txt NOT be in the directory with your other files or it's name will be included in your output.

Comment: Hi John,

Let's take one file for example:
the file name is abc_1.txt   
Probably, Joe wants 1 as the header in the same file. but 1 should be taken from file name and put in the abc_1.txt file..

Answer (score 0):

let's take one file for example:
the file name is abc_1.txt
Probably, Joe wants 1 in the header of same file. but 1 should taken from file name and put in the abc_1.txt file. please find the attched picture for your refrence

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6mcHp.jpg)